# Solving for integral curves of a vector field - how to account for changing charts?

Tags: differential-geometry

[Ref. 'Core Principles of Special and General Relativity by Luscombe]

Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\supset I\to M$ be a curve that we'll parameterize using $t$, i.e. $\gamma(t)\in M$. It's stated that:

> If $\gamma(t)$ has coordinates $x^i(t)$ and [a vector field] $X$ has components $X^i$, finding the integral curve associated with $X$ reduces to solving a set of coupled first-order differential equations, $$\frac{d}{dt}x^i=X^i(x^1(t),\ldots,x^n(t))$$

Immediately after there's an example: if $X=x\partial_x+y\partial_y$, then $dx/dt=x$ and $dy/dt=y$, which gives the integral curve passing through $(a,b)$ at $t=0$ as $\gamma(t)=(ae^t,be^t)$.

---

**Doubt**: Referring to the phrase "If $\gamma(t)$ has coordinates $x^i(t)$...", I'm guessing it's unlikely that **all** the points on the curve belong to a single chart. So how can we claim only one coordinate system $x^i$ to represent the coordinates of **all** the points on the curve? Won't we have to adjust the coordinates according to the chart?

e.g. if some $p,p'\in\gamma(I)$ are covered by different charts, and if the coordinates of $p$ are $x^i$, won't the coordinates of $p'$ have to be characterized by an entirely different coordinate system (e.g. some $y^i$)?

---

**My current thought process is as follows**: [Referring to the example above] Consider any point $p\in M$. Can I say that whatever coordinate system $\{x, y\}$ is used at $p$ (in accordance with whatever chart covers it), the coordinates of $X_{p}$ in the *coordinate basis corresponding to the coordinate system* will be $x,y$?

Put another way, if I use coordinate system $\{a,b\}$ at a point $p_1$, then the components of $X_{p_1}$ will just be $a,b$. And if I use some other coordinate system $\{u,v\}$ at some other point $p_2$, then the coordinates of $X_{p_2}$ will now be $u,v$.

And what this implies for the integral curve that we calculate, i.e. $(ae^t,be^t)$, is that if $\gamma(t_0)=p_0$ and $\gamma(t_1)=p_1$, then **$(ae^{t_0},be^{t_0})$ are the coordinates of the integral curve at $p_0$ in the coordinate basis $(x,y)$**, **while $(ae^{t_1},be^{t_1})$ are the coordinates of the integral curve at $p_1$ in the coordinate basis $(u,v)$**. In essence, we're coming up with local solutions to the curve and "stitching them together".

Does the above seem correct or are there any mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the answer to your "put another way" paragraph is no; coordinate charts don't generally behave that nicely. Consider Cartesian and polar coordinates for a counterexample. The example you're referring to is implicitly saying they're taking $\{x, y\}$ to be standard (Cartesian) coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and in these coordinates $X = x\partial_x + y\partial_y$. Then one can check that in polar coordinates $\{r, \theta\}$, this same vector field is given by $X = r\partial_r$ (NOT $r\partial_r + \theta\partial_\theta$). This is the change of coordinates formula for vector fields.

Let us examine the integral curves in both coordinate systems now. As you said, in the Cartesian coordinate system, the solution curve $\gamma(t)$ is given by $\gamma(t) = (a e^t, be^t)$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. The polar coordinate expression for this curve is given by
$$
r(t) = \sqrt{a^2 e^{2t} + b^2 e^{2t}} = e^{t}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = r_0 e^t, \ \ \ \ \theta(t) = \theta_0 = \arctan(b/a).
$$
Thus in polar coordinates $\gamma$ is given by $\gamma(t) = (r_0 e^t, \theta_0)$. We got this from changing coordinates in the expression for $\gamma$, but we could start with the expression for $X$ in polar coordinates and solve the ODE
$$
\dot \gamma(t) = r\partial_r \implies \gamma(t) = r_0 e^t,  \ \theta(t) = \theta_0.
$$
The idea of "stitching things together", though, is what you want to think of when your curve isn't covered by one chart.

Comment: Ah I see! So basically, at any given point $p$, using whatever coordinate system we've specified the coordinates of the vector field at that point, i.e. of $X_p$ - the integral curve coordinates **at that point will be expressed in the same coordinate system**. Hope that's correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I do want to stress, though, that at any point $p$ there are an infinite number of possible charts, so while you *could* express the vector field in coordinates $x, y$ and then express the curve in different coordinates $u, v$, it makes more sense to express both in the same chart. For instance, like we did above, we can express a vector field in Cartesian coords, solve in those coords, and then also express the integral curves in polar coords. It's a matter of personal taste/what method suits the problem best.

Comment: At the risk of being repetitive: you can express both the vector field and its integral curves in whatever chart you want (different or the same). But a priori there is no symbolic, obvious relationship between the expression in one chart v.s. another; the relationship is exactly given by the change of coordinates formulas.

Comment: Understood. What I meant was : when we solve for the integral curve, **then** we get its coordinates in the same coordinate system as used to express the vector field components **at that point**. And as you said, later on nothing stops us from transforming those coordinates to a different system, depending on the problem. Hope i got that right (and I guess even I'm repeating myself). And thanks so much for patiently explaining everything! Appreciate it